# AWS S3: distributed concatenation of tens of millions of json files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with tens of millions of relatively small json files, each less than 10 K.

To analyze them, I would like to merge them into a small number of files, each having one json per line (or some other separator), and several thousands of such lines.

This would allow me to more easily (and performantly) use all kind of big data tools out there.

Now, it is clear to me this cannot be done with one command or function call, but rather a distributed solution is needed, because of the amount of files involved.

The question is if there is something ready and packaged or must I pull out my own solution.

Answer (score 2):

don't know of anything out there that can do this out of the box, but you can pretty easily do it yourself. the solution also depends a lot on how fast you need to get this done.

2 suggestions:
1) list all the files, split the list, download sections, merge and reupload.

2) list all the files, and after them go through them one at a time and read/download and write it to a kinesis steam. configure kinesis to dump the files to s3 via kinesis firehose.

In both scenarios the tricky bit is going to be handling failures and ensuring you don't get the data multiple times.

For completeness, if the files would be larger (>5MB) you could also leverage http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html which would allow you to merge files in S3 directly without having to download.

Comment: kinesis firehose is pretty close to what I need

Comment: yep. you still need to read the file contents and push it through the firehose though.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming each json file is one line only, then I would do:

```
cat * >> bigfile
```

This will concat all files in a directory into the new file `bigfile`.

You can now read `bigfile` one line at a time, json decode the line and do something interesting with it.

If your json files are formatted for readability, then you will first need to [combine all the lines in the file into one line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164056/how-do-i-combine-all-lines-in-a-text-file-into-a-single-line).